# Programatically setting the default state of items in a layout xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I decided to avoid for now the set preferences method for setting user settings. Im a noobie to android and xml.
I have a layout that I display with various radio buttons, check boxes, and selectable imagebuttons.  I would like to know how after I display the layout (nothing is set) to change the display to match the stored user preferences programatically.  And also how to query each item on the layout screen for its selected state.  Some of my settings.xml code.  Variables for the two items are WifiOn and AirplaneOn.

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CkBxAutoWifiStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="ToggleAutoWifiOnOff"
    android:text="Turn Wifi On If Off" />

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ckBxAutoAirPlane"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="ToggleAutoAirPlaneModeOnOff"
    android:text="Turn Air Plane Mode Off If On" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to set each component in the onResume of your setting activity.

First you need to have a reference to each component.

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

On your onResume just check in shared preferences and set the state of each component.

```
myCheckBox.setChecked(true);
```

is that or maybe i misunderstood the question?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Needed to add CheckBox myCheckBox =  findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

Comment: Needed to add the cast (CHECKBOX) to your answer.                                                   CheckBox myCheckBox = (CHECKBOX) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);               I'll give you the answer credit if you can give me what goes in the  question mark area of this instruction. public setSettings(View v).                 \\   setContentView(R.layout.settings);setSettings(??? ); How do I get the View of R.layout.settings?  I'm tired sorry.

Comment: Guess I had one braincell left. Answer is SetContentView(R.layout.settings);
View v = (View) findViewById(R.layout.settings);
setSettings(v);